# Cannot resolve symbol "Intent"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I am having a problem with importing Intent and View in android studio.
Everything was working fine and all of sudden this error popped up!

here is how i am importing both `Intent` and `View` in the `MainActivity.java` Class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
```

here is a picture of the error i am getting

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFapo.png)

i am having the same errors in other activities also,other than `MainActivity.java`

Comment: try clean and re-run your project with good internet connection

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi when i try to run the project i get this error `error running app Default Activity not found`

Comment: Go to Android Studio>File>Invalidate Chaches/Restart. This will work.

Comment: @ankuranurag2 i tried this thousand times and unfortunately  it didnt work

Comment: If you recently changed Manifest.xml, be sure defined your activity in it and has `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`. most common problem is because you have mistake in xml files such as manifest and layouts. check them (if you use git, try to check differents with previous version)

Comment: Add your manifest to the question please.

Comment: I had a problem in the layout of my main activity. all the other errors was caused by this error

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

- Rebuilding the project
- Cleaning the project
- Syncing with Gradle Files
- Closing the Project, closing AS and relaunching / reopening
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Double checking all support libraries are up to date in the SDK manager
- Exit Android Studio
- Back up your project
- Delete all the .iml files and the .idea folder, build folder
- Relaunch Android Studio and reimport your project